# Renew auth token worked but failed to save. What now?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Requested to renew an auth token about to expire. Got the new token back but app failed to save it due to bug. Now cannot request a new one because the old one is considered expired. What recourse is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only recourse here is to have the end-user disconnect their app, and then reconnect it.

Comment: Thanks, clearly you're right. I would think there must some way to test the reconnect process programmatically without having to use a live token.

Comment: You can test it yourself by using their OAuth playground to generate a token that's already within the 30-day expiration bounds. Store those tokens, and then call your reconnect code to make sure it works.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Also,
Taken from: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

- The token expires after expires time (2 hours is the default).
- The user changes her password which invalidates the access token.
- The user de-authorizes your app.
- The user logs out of Facebook.

  **Token expires after expires time**

This scenario refers to the use case where a user has authorized your app in the past, but the access token that you were issued has expired.When you try to make Graph API call on her behalf you will get an HTTP 400 with the following error in the body:

```
  { 
      error: {
        type: "OAuthException",
        message: "Session has expired at unix time 
          SOME_TIME. The current unix time is SOME_TIME.”
      }, 
    }
```

**Scenario 2: User changes her password**

```
This scenario refers to use case where a user has authorized your app in the past and then she changes the password associated with her Facebook account. In this scenario, when you try to make Graph API call on her behalf you will get an HTTP 400 with the following error in the body:

{ 
  error: {
    type: "OAuthException",
    message: "The session has been invalidated because 
      the user has changed the password.",
  }, 
}

Please note that you will receive this message even if your app was granted the offline_access permission if the user changed their password.
```

**Scenario 3: User de-authorizes your app**

```
This scenario refers to a use case where a user has authorized your app in the past, but then she de-authorizes your app by going to the App Dashboard. In this scenario when you try to make a Graph API call on her behalf you will get a HTTP 400 with the following error in the body:

{
  error: {
    type: "OAuthException",
    message: "Error validating access token: USER_ID
      has not authorized application APP_ID",
  },
}

Please note that even if the user had authorized your app with the offline_access permission access tokens will become invalid if the user de-authorizes your app.
```

**Scenario 4: User logs out of Facebook**

This scenario refers to a use case where a user has authorized your app in the past and then she logs out of Facebook. If the user authorized your app with the offline_access permission then the Graph API call works as expected. If the user did not grant this permission and you try to make a Graph API call on behalf of the user, you will get an HTTP 400 with the following error in the body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating 
      access token: The session is invalid because the 
      user logged out."
   }
}
```

Comment: This question was supposed to be part of the Intuit Partner Platform groups of questions (QuickBooks). Sorry if that was not clear.